Is it possible to add the hardwired Garmin eRTL615 to the Specialized Turbo Vado 4.0?
I have a Specialized Turbo Vado 4.0 Step-Thru.  I'd like to add a Garmin rear radar unit to it.  While the battery-powered RTL515 should work no problem, the ebike-specific, hardwired Garmin eRTL615 would be ideal to avoid the inconvenience of charging.
The Turbo Vado 5.0 includes the Garmin eRTL615, though of course this doesn't necessarily mean there's wiring available for the 4.0.
I haven't been able to find a clear answer by searching online to find out if this is possible or not.  I'd appreciate any guidance as to what kit or parts might work.

If you have already done some research online, you have probably found that Specialized publishes the list of spare parts, and it seems that there are enough references to "retrofit" a eRTL615 (the only unknown being the connection between the "splitter" and the radar itself). For the rest, the connection between the radar and the bike is probably wireless so shouldn't be a issue - unless intentional limitations, not uncommon in the e-bike world. Best is probably to check with a Specialized dealer.
